# Is there any PHP library for simple form to database saving?

Tags: php, forms

I have to make simple form that is saved to database, is there any simple and easy PHP framework for this purpose?

Comment: This is so easy by itself that I doubt someone would bother to write a framework for that. What are you looking for in particular? What is the framework supposed to provide?

Comment: **Never.** The term "framework" itself stands for "something fat and bloated"

Comment: There's Google Docs: http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=87809.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call [Formtools](http://www.formtools.org/) a framework, but it is an excellent form processing tool. It sounds like it would handle what you're looking.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know this is what you looking for and its aint simple also
Try look http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need a framework for your entire site or not. I have found that [livesite](http://www.camelback.net/) is very easy to use and you can create forms and so on without any code.